# Frequency Analyzer in C#

Tags: c#, audio, analysis, wav, frequency

I'm looking for a C# source code that performs a frequency analysis on a WAV file and displays the results in a graph, similar to the one displayed in apps like WavePad.
Do you know where I can find such a code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's in a very experimental state at the moment, but if you have a look at the WPFDemo project in [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio), it performs an FFT on the incoming microphone data or sound file you play and plots it under the wave-form.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find where the app displays the WAV frequency. In fact, as soon as I loaded a WAV file and clicked "Play", it crashed...

Comment: if you report the details of the error, I'll have a look into it. 
The FFT is drawn here:
http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/28568#597541

Comment: Can NAudio be routed to use the main system sound source? i.e. pick up windows' beeps and bleeps?

Comment: @joshcomley it might be possible with the CoreAudio wrappers for Vista and Win7, but I haven't experimented much with them yet