# NSData to .wav file and then to Ultrasound (20 to 22 KHz)

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-transfer, format-conversion

In my app I have to do data transfer via ultrasound (20 to 22 kHz).. I have one idea to do that... i.e.,

At Sending side:

1.First I ll convert my data(NSdata or NSString ... ) to .wav file(I really don't know is it possible?)

2.I ll convert that converted .wav file to ultrasound (20 to 22 KHz) or simply play that in loud speaker

At receiving side:

1.It ll convert received ultrasound(20 to 22 kHz) or recorded .wav file from other device to NSData

My question is, Is it possible to convert data(NSdata or NSString ... ) to .wav file?, and then is it possible to produce ultrasound(20 to 22KHz) from .wav file?  It may look silly... I don't know It ll work.. But please tell ur idea about this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034346/ios-how-to-produce-ultrasonic-sound

Comment: You're making this putative link acoustically?  A quick check of the iPhone microphone frequency response suggests significant fall-off above 20 kHz.

Comment: @Maulik - I seen this link... I think I have to step back of generating ultrasonic sound...  if there is any possibility to generate NSData to sound

Comment: I don't know how to convert NSData to .wav file but some one did it in java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483662/convert-data-to-sound-and-back. But If u have find solution to convert NSData to .wav file u can play it in variable frequency by http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I merely designed a way to this. I didn't work it out, but I think it will give you an idea.

At sending side:

1. first convert your `NSData` to byte stream
2. then convert that byte stream to .wav file
3. then play your .wav file with (20 to 22 kHz) by http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html

At receiving side:

1. play your received sound(20 to 22 kHz) by http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html
2. then convert low frequency .wav file to byte stream
3. then convert byte stream to `NSData`