# How to create sound spectrogram in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, wav

How to create spectrogram from wav sound file ? Who know such libraries for .NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Frequency Analyzer in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377661/frequency-analyzer-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bass.net library > http://bass.radio42.com/