# Real Time Graph Drawing (Waveform)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, drawing

I'd like to do some projects with audio in C# .NET 4.0 in the future so I've gathered some code samples for audio recording, working with WAVE files etc. But what I haven't been able to find is:

How can I draw audio waveforms / spectrograms in realtime(ish)? Obviously, creating an in-memory bitmap and loading it into a picture box would be very slow, right? So, what's the easiest way?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question - check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606367/how-to-create-sound-spectrogram-in-c  (C#, despite link)

Comment: For real time waveform display you might want to look into hardware accelerated graphics - I don't think poor old GDI+ would be able to cope too well. I'd say the best thing to do is simply to send a ring-buffer containing the audio data straight to the graphics card for rendering by a shader to a texture. You could even do the FFT in the shader if you wanted :)

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this one as well. Forum lore claims that Direct2D is the fastest .NET screen-painting API, but I have never seen a WinForms app that uses it. Must you use WinForms?

Comment: holtavolt, I saw those questions but it doesn't look like there were any satisfactory answers/links. One, on codeproject used "unsafe" code to draw the images. I'd rather find the "right" way to do it...

Comment: Depending on your requirements, GDI+ should be plenty fast enough for a spectrogram. I've created 3D CAD programs in GDI+ that ran smoothly on a HD monitor in fullscreen on a first-generation netbook. There are many things you can do to speed up things. Your audio processing could be a bottleneck, but even this should be no problem for a computer in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GDI+ based [Graphics and Drawing in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a36fascx.aspx) to draw your content directly.  This will be far faster than rendering to a bitmap and displaying in a picture box for constantly changing content.

Comment: Well for a spectrogram, I'd have to draw what essentially amounts to a bitmap. Does GDI+ handle this well?

Comment: @John Relatively well - it'll still be faster than drawing into a bitmap and rendering.

Comment: I disagree. Drawing on-screen control is slower than drawing to a bitmap and changing it. I tried it with stopwatch. 5K line. Here is the results:
On-screen Control : 2772ms
Bitmap & change : 85ms
Double buffered on-screen control : 2657ms

Answer (score 1):

Just paint directly on a suitable control surface, i.e. a Panel. Get the graphics context of the control and update it in the Paint-event using the Invalidate() function. Every time you invalidate, Paint is called automagically. This is where you want to put your drawing logic.

The best way to update it is to use DrawImageUnscaled(). The image itself is fastest made with the LockBits method, explained excellently here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx