# Is there any c# way [to get]/[library which provides the] sound frequency info?

Tags: c#, audio, microphone, frequency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Frequency Analyzer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377661/frequency-analyzer-in-c-sharp)

I am looking for easy way(or any way) to get the current sound frequency from the computer microphone.  I would like to make a guitar tuner of my own.

How to get this frequency using C#?

Is there any algorithm if such library does not exist?

Comment: But i would like the real time sound. Not the audio file.

Comment: Most sound is a combination of frequencies, unless your sound source is a pure sine wave.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It will be close to it. I would like to make a guitar tuner of my own.

Comment: [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) is the algorithm you're looking for, and there are plenty of implementations around. Now all you need is the PCM audio data from your mic.

Comment: @NikoDrašković Is there any c# library which provides that one. I have no reason to implement it by my own.

Comment: I'd give [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp) a try :) (I believe I've actually used the one in the second answer, but that was a long time ago...)

Comment: @NikoDrašković Please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm.

There should be a fair number of implementations in C#, and some of those could be found in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp).